# RabbitMQ Shovel plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying use shovel plugin  and getting the following error message

```
Supervisor: {<0.6616.0>,
                                       rabbit_shovel_dyn_worker_sup}
 Context:    child_terminated
 Reason:     {{badmatch,{error,handshake_receive_timed_out}},
              [{rabbit_shovel_worker,make_conn_and_chan,1},
               {rabbit_shovel_worker,handle_cast,2},
               {gen_server2,handle_msg,2},
               {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
           {name,{<<"/">>,<<"s2s">>}},
              {mfargs,
                  {rabbit_shovel_worker,start_link,
                      [dynamic,
                       {<<"/">>,<<"s2s">>},
                       [{<<"src-uri">>,
                         <<"amqp://guest:guest@102.29.83.40:15672/">>},
                        {<<"src-queue">>,<<"helloWorldForAll">>},
                        {<<"dest-uri">>,
                         <<"amqp://tester:tester@iteam:15672/">>},
                        {<<"dest-queue">>,<<"helloWorldForAll">>},
                        {<<"add-forward-headers">>,false},
                        {<<"ack-mode">>,<<"on-confirm">>},
                        {<<"delete-after">>,<<"never">>}]]}},
              {restart_type,{transient,1}},
              {shutdown,4294967295},
              {child_type,worker}]
```

wonder where i am going wrong , i am new to rabbitmq

Comment: maybe the reason is that you are trying to connect with default guest:guest account or `iteam:15672` is not reachable?

Comment: password seems to be right ! wonder if there is step by step debugging! like getting an error password entered was wrong. then can focus on other probable error!

Comment: got it done , Issue now closed

Comment: Can you explain to others bumping on this question later what was the actual problem and how did you solve it?